# Javascript/jQuery Update Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, graphite

I wrote the following code which works correctly, I'm creating a new array that takes each two members from numbers and divide them. Sample:

```js
var numbers = [{ "name": "testvalue", "data": [10] }, 
               { "name": "testtotal", "data": [2]  }, 
               { "name": "prodvalue", "data": [10] }, 
               { "name": "prodtotal", "data": [2]  }];

var mydata = $.grep(numbers, function(e) {
    return new RegExp('^test*').test(e.name)
});

console.log(mydata) // prints [{"name": "testvalue", "data": [10]}, {"name": "testtotal", "data": [2]}]

result = [{
    "name": "testresult",
    "data": [mydata[0]["data"] / mydata[1]["data"]]
}];

console.log(result) // [{"name": "testresult", "data": [5]}]
```

My question is about efficiency, is what I'm doing efficient or is there a better way to do things? (I'm new to JS/jQuery that's why I'm asking).

I don't care about the content of numbers, All I want is divide every two elements, every element name ends with total or value

Sample real data as requested. specifically the data is coming from graphite/d3.json

```js
var data = 
[ {"target": "xs12t11.Busy",  "datapoints": [34,54,65,76,87] }, 
  {"target": "xs12t11.Total", "datapoints": [34,54,2,12,33]} ];
```

Comment: Do you have control over `numbers`?  If so, there are better ways to represent that structure.  It's not very clear what you are doing here, partly because array indexes aren't all that informative.

Comment: yeah the problem is that this data is coming from d3.json and unfortunately I have no control over, but basically each element will have two hashes with names "total" and "value"

Comment: plus I can't do this request twice so yes I'm stuck. my way works but I just thought of taking opinions of experts here.

Comment: As long as your dataset is small or you're not searching it a lot, this won't kill you performance wise.

Comment: I have 43 items (43*2) exactly. I would like to do them sequentially i/i+1 but I'm afraid that d3.json doesn't return an even number of records for some reason ...

Comment: Could you provide part of the larger list and what you want to see out of it?  I can take another look later unless someone else here does first.

Comment: Thanks I will basically the name field is the server name, with two metrics total connections and busy connections. My JS should output utilization = busy/total*100 .... for all servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not entirely sure I understand your requirements.  I've provided two examples that iterate over `data` and translate it into a result.

Given the following input with the potential for an odd number of rows:

```
var data = 
[ {"target": "xs12t11.Busy",  "datapoints": [34,54,65,76,87] }, 
  {"target": "xs12t11.Total", "datapoints": [34,54,2,12,33]  }, 
  {"target": "xs12t12.Busy",  "datapoints": [34,54,2,12,33]} ];
```

**Example 1** Sums up the series in each row and gives a result with a single average per pair of rows:

```
function sum(inArr) {
    var retVal = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < inArr.length; ++i) retVal += inArr[i];
    return retVal;
}


var result = [];

// Increment by 2 to grab records in pairs
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2) {
    var series1 = data[i];
    var series2 = data[i+1];

    // Series1 always exists, but series2 may not
    if(!series2) break;

    result.push({
        name: series1.target.split('.')[0],
        data: sum(series1.datapoints)/sum(series2.datapoints)
    });
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

**Output**

```
[{"name":"xs12t11","data":2.3407407407407406}]
```

**Example 2** Returns results for each pair of rows with a series of averages:

```
function avgSeries(series1, series2) {
    var retVal = [];
    var len = Math.min(series1.length, series2.length);

    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) retVal.push(series1[i]/series2[i]);
    return retVal;
}

var result = [];

// Increment by 2 to grab records in pairs
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2) {
    var series1 = data[i];
    var series2 = data[i+1];

    // Series1 always exists, but series2 may not
    if(!series2) break;

    result.push({
        name: series1.target.split('.')[0],
        data: avgSeries(series1.datapoints, series2.datapoints)
    });
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

**Output**

```
[{"name":"xs12t11","data":[1,1,32.5,6.333333333333333,2.6363636363636362]}]
```

If neither of these are inline with what you are looking to do, let me know.

Comment: Thank you! that's more than what I have expected :)